# Instagram hashtag validator

Tags: validation, instagram, hashtag

Is there any official library for validating Instagram hashtags?

Take Twitter for example, they provide https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text for validating hashtags.

The only official thing I can find is the user guide [How do I use hashtags?](https://help.instagram.com/351460621611097), but it just vaguely describe the rules:

> Numbers are allowed in hashtags. However, spaces and special characters, like $ or %, won't work.

As far as I know, the hashtag validation rules are different. For example, #123 is not a valid hashtag on Twitter, but it's valid on Instagram.

If there is no official library for validating Instagram hashtags, what is the next best thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that nobody recommends a library, so I created one: https://github.com/johnlinp/instagram-validator. Any issue report or pull request is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler than that:

You want to check that the hashtag contains only alphanumerical characters. I don't believe uppercase letters are valid.

So the Regex to do this is simple:

```
^[a-z0-9]+$
```

Comment: I believe that non-English characters are valid too. For example, "#味噌汁" is the Japanese for "miso soup" and it's a valid hashtag on Instagram. You can see it at https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/%E5%91%B3%E5%99%8C%E6%B1%81/

Comment: @johnlinp: perhaps, but then there's the question of "do you expect Japanese characters to appear"

Comment: Yes - I don't have any assumptions on what the language will be.